# Configure alpine-sqs for codeception testing

Tags: php, docker-compose, amazon-sqs, codeception

Im trying to run [API tests](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/REST) enabling [Queue](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Queue) module in codeception.
Im running a project which consists on an api running on a vagrant machine, [alpine-sqs](https://github.com/roribio/alpine-sqs) is running on host:

`http://localhost:9325/` web interface of alpine-sqs

`http://localhost:9324/queue/default` default alpine-sqs queue

I didnt modify default alpine-sqs config. And I have the following configuration in my codeception api suite:

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Symfony:
            app_path: src
            environment: dev
        - REST:
            url: /api
            depends: Symfony
        - Queue
        - \Helper\Api
        - Asserts
    config:
        Queue:
            'type': 'aws'
            'endpoint': 'http://10.0.2.2:9324'
            'version': '2012-11-05'
            'region': 'eu-central-1'
```

When I run the following test:

```
<?php
$I->seeQueueExists('default');
$I->clearQueue('default');
$I->addMessageToQueue('this is a message', 'default');
$I->seeQueueHasCurrentCount('default', 1);
?>
```

It fails and the last step throwing the following:

```
1) CorrectCreationCest: Send valid creation request
 Test  tests/api/campaigns/create/CorrectCreationCest.php:sendValidCreationRequest
 Fail  Failed asserting that '0' matches expected 1.

Scenario Steps:

 4. $I->seeQueueHasCurrentCount("default",1) at tests/api/campaigns/create/CorrectCreationCest.php:111
 3. $I->addMessageToQueue("this is a message","default") at tests/api/campaigns/create/CorrectCreationCest.php:110
 2. $I->clearQueue("default") at tests/api/campaigns/create/CorrectCreationCest.php:109
 1. $I->seeQueueExists("default") at tests/api/campaigns/create/CorrectCreationCest.php:108
```

Somehow codeception achieves connecting to alpine-sqs and retrieves queues correctly but when checking message in queue fails, I dont know why.

Thanks

Comment: Could it be a problem of your SQS queue? I've looked at the source code: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.4.5/src/Codeception/Lib/Driver/AmazonSQS.php#L87-L88
It reads attribute named `ApproximateNumberOfMessages`. Off by one is a quite good approximation :)

Comment: Uhmmm, maybe, but im using default sqs queue from alpine-sqs, so it shouldnt be causing this behaviour, I think this could be a wrong configuration problem with my custom endpoint, but it should be working as it is... Ive tried producing messages and consuming them using aws cli from guest machine and its working properly, it doesnt seem to be a problem with my queue.